# Ocultar icono de pausa en videoplayer

Tags: flutter, dart

(Soy nuevo en flutter) Como el titulo lo dice banda, quiero ocultar o hacer inivisble el icono de pausa al momento de reproducir un video, He intentado con el visibility() pero aun sin exito. Los iconos los muestro en el centro de pantalla ya que es una aplicación de videos. Dejo mi codigo en donde al momento de tocar la pantalla pauso o reproduzco segun sea el caso.

```
InkWell(
          child: Center(
            child: Icon(
              videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                  ? Icons.pause
                  : Icons.play_arrow,
              size: 80,
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () async {
            setState(() {
              videoPlayerController!.value.isPlaying
                  ? videoPlayerController!.pause()
                  : videoPlayerController!.play();
            });
          },
        ),
```

El icono de reproducir se comporta bien, pero al momento de reproducir el video se queda el icono de pausa en todo el video.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No termino de entender la pregunta o la duda... ¿Podrías redactarlo de otra forma? También mencionas que has usado el widget Visibility, pero en el código expuesto, no lo veo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo realice de la siguiente manera:

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(
      _videoCtrl.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause: Icons.play_arrow,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        if(_videoCtrl.value.isPlaying){
          _videoCtrl.pause();
        }else{
          _videoCtrl.play();
        }
      });
    },
  ),
```